# Python command line using Cygwin: ImportError

Tags: python, cygwin

My python files are as follows:

```
/root/D/main.py
/root/T/test.py
/root/T/__init__.py
```

My `main.py` imports:

```
from T import test
```

I executed the `main.py` from command line:

```
> export PYTHONPATH=/cygdrive/root/T
> cd /root/D
> python main.py
```

I get error: 
`ImportError: No module named T.`

How can I execute from command line without error?

Edit:
The contents of the `__init__.py` is:

```
from .test import *
```

Comment: Actually, while this may not cause the error, you created a package called `T`, with the `__init__.py` file in that directory. Therefore, you may want to set your `PYTHONPATH=/root`, and use something like `from T.test import something`. But, since `test.py` lives in your `PYTHONPATH`, it should be picked up.

Comment: Is `from test import something` the only line in `main.py`?

Comment: Hi. No, it's not the only line, it's a 1000 line file.

Comment: Sorry, edited it, there was error in import line.

Comment: Ok, with your edit, see my first comment. Change your `PYTHONPATH`.

Comment: Just changing the `PYTHONPATH` to `root` didn't help. The error is `ImportError: No module named T.`

Comment: Perhaps pedantic, but did you set it to `root` or to `/root`?

Comment: I set it to `/root` of course.

Comment: OK, resolved it. the problem was Cygwin, I set `PYTHONPATH=/cygdrive/root` and the proper way is `PYTHONPATH=c:/root`.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved it, the problem was Cygwin, I set `PYTHONPATH=/cygdrive/root` and the proper way is `PYTHONPATH=c:/root`